# How can I use a csv file to get a list of IMDb URLs?

Tags: python, csv, url, imdb

I have a .csv file with 1000 movies (https://github.com/LearnDataSci/articles/blob/master/Python%20Pandas%20Tutorial%20A%20Complete%20Introduction%20for%20Beginners/IMDB-Movie-Data.csv) and have been set the task of getting IMDb URLs for all 1000 movies.

I've tried using Cinemagoer, but I don't particularly want to plug in all 1000 titles by hand. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: I need the IMDb links, I only have the title (not the link).

Comment: IMDB offer an API through AWS Data Exchange. That's probably what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the table and use the 'title' column for Cinemagoer queries.
Then you can get ID and just form an URL.

```py
import requests
import csv
from imdb import Cinemagoer
from io import StringIO

TABLE_URL = 'https://github.com/LearnDataSci/articles/raw/master/Python%20Pandas%20Tutorial%20A%20Complete%20Introduction%20for%20Beginners/IMDB-Movie-Data.csv'


def get_table(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    return StringIO(r.content.decode())


def search_movie(interface, name):
    movies = interface.search_movie(name)

    return movies[0] if len(movies) > 0 else None


def form_url(movie):
    return f'http://imdb.com/title/tt{movie.movieID}'


def main():
    ia = Cinemagoer()

    reader_obj = csv.reader(
        get_table(TABLE_URL)
    )

    # Skip column names
    next(reader_obj)

    for row in reader_obj:
        # 1 - is column with names
        print(
            form_url(
                search_movie(ia, row[1])
            )
        )


main()
```